# Change JSON format/layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a universal variable on my website which includes line items with relevant details. These line items are reflective of what the user has in their cart. I am integrating with a third party who require the data passed through to them to be formatted slightly different. The below is the data layer currently on my website:

```
"lineItems": [
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "s83y016b5",
            "sku_code": "s83y016b5",
            "url": "/en-gb/jeans/p/s83y016b5",
            "image_url": "http://www.my-website.com/a/p/shirt.jpeg",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "manufacturer": "",
            "category": "Everyday Wear",
            "stock": 116,
            "currency": "GBP",
            "unit_sale_price": 16,
            "unit_price": 16,
            "size": "6-9 Months",
            "color": "Indigo"
        },
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

The below is what format the third party needs:

```
"lineItems": [
  {
    "sku": "s83y016b5",
    "name": "Jeans",
    "description": "A super great pair of jeans.",
    "category": "Everyday Wear",
    "other": {"fieldName": "This can be a string or any value you like"}
    "unitPrice": 11.99,
    "salePrice": 11.99,
    "quantity": 2,
    "totalPrice": 23.98
    "imageUrl": "http://www.my-website.com/a/p/shirt.jpeg",
    "productUrl": "http://www.my-website.com/index.php/shirt.html",
  }]
```

Obviously this needs to be dynamic based on the products in the cart. What I intend to do is use javascript to amend the data and send this to the third party via Google Tag Manager.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any questions welcome.

Comment: Why is it `quantity: 1` in the input, `quantity: 2` in the result?

Comment: Can you explain each property and its conversion?

Comment: Where is it supposed to get the `description` and `productUrl` from?

Comment: Ignore the data itself it's more the JSON format I need to amend to match what the third party needs.

Comment: To respond to stack overflow, this is only part of a larger amount of data I am sending to the third party, I have managed to get the rest sorted fine it's the format of the line items I am struggling with.

Comment: You loop through the input array, create a new object with the properties you want, and push it onto the result array. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Barmar amended the code

Comment: I don't see any code? If you mean you got rid of the extra array, I already noticed that and deleted my comment.

Comment: `newLineItems = oldLineItems.map(obj => ({ new object properties in here }))`

Answer (score 0):

This should be close to what you're looking for.

```
let oldLineItems = "your object"; 

let newLineItems = {};
newLineItems.lineItems = [];

for (let i in oldLineItems.lineItems) {
    newLineItems.lineItems[i] = {};
    for (let key in oldLineItems.lineItems[i].product)
    {
        newLineItems.lineItems[i][key] = oldLineItems.lineItems[i].product[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See code below. 
I'm not sure how your lineItems object is set up, but below I just created an array called line Items. If line items is a key in an object which I suspect from your snippet above, you will have to go a level deeper in the for loops used in my example below.

Simply add further details to the new object in the nested for in loops below.

```js
var lineItems =
[
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "s83y016b5",
            "sku_code": "s83y016b5",
            "url": "/en-gb/jeans/p/s83y016b5",
            "image_url": "http://www.my-website.com/a/p/shirt.jpeg",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "manufacturer": "",
            "category": "Everyday Wear",
            "stock": 116,
            "currency": "GBP",
            "unit_sale_price": 16,
            "unit_price": 16,
            "size": "6-9 Months",
            "color": "Indigo",
            "description": 'Some random description'
        },
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "id": "s83y01699",
            "sku_code": "s83y01699",
            "url": "/en-gb/pants/p/s83y016b5",
            "image_url": "http://www.my-website.com/a/p/pants.jpeg",
            "name": "Pants",
            "manufacturer": "",
            "category": "Casual Wear",
            "stock": 90,
            "currency": "au",
            "unit_sale_price": 14,
            "unit_price": 14,
            "size": "6-9 Months",
            "color": "Indigo",
            "description": 'Some random description'
        },
        "quantity": 14
    },
];

var newLineItems = [];

for(var char in lineItems){
 // Adding some values to newLineItems.
 newLineItems.push({
  sku: lineItems[char].product.sku_code,
  name: lineItems[char].product.name,
  description: lineItems[char].product.description,
  category: lineItems[char].product.category,
  quantity: lineItems[char].quantity
 });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newLineItems));
```

Comment: Many thanks for the above it has helped me get closer to finishing this off...finally :)